# With Bazel how do I make part of one genrules' source files (e.g. header files) available to another genrule?

Tags: bazel, bazel-genrule

Maybe this is a no-brainer and I just didn't get the concept yet.

I have a genrule, basically wrapping an existing `make`/`config` workflow to integrate it into a Bazel-based build configuration. In my example I'd like to build `openssl`, and then (with the same approach) some library depending on `openssl`, say `xmlsec1`

My (shortened) rule for `openssl` looks like this:

```
genrule(
    name = "build",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    srcs = glob(["**/*"], exclude=["bazel-*"]),
    outs =  [
        "libssl.a",
        "libcrypto.a",
        "include/openssl/opensslconf.h",
    ],
    cmd = """
        OUT_DIR="$$(realpath $(RULEDIR))"
        pushd "$$(dirname $(location config))"
        ./config
        make
        make -j6 DESTDIR="$$OUT_DIR" install_sw install_ssldirs
    """
)
```

This builds fine and `$OUT_DIR` contains all files I need to build against `openssl`

I'd now like to create another `genrule` building `xmlsec1` which needs the path to `openssl`s header files.

Now if I want to access a header, say `include/opensslv.h` it won't be part of `@openssl//:build`s artifacts since I didn't explicitly listing it in `outs`. But doing so results in

```
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/bla/blubb/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/f68917ddf601b6533d6db04f8101d580/external/openssl/BUILD.bazel", line 37, column 8, in <toplevel>
        genrule(
Error in genrule: rule 'build' has file 'include/openssl/opensslv.h' as both an input and an output
```

which is correct of course, but what can I do about it?

Removing those header files from `srcs` doen't work neither, since they wouldn't be available at build time.

One way would be to `make install` `openssl` to some destination directory, listing each of the dozens of header files explicitly and using that prefix in all dependent projects. But that doesn't feel right.

What's the recommended way to pass lists of files from one `genrule` to another?

Comment: there's also https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_foreign_cc/main/cmake.html which might be better than writing genrules by hand, if it works for your use case

Answer (score 1):

`xmlsec1` could have `include/openssl/opensslv.h` in its own `srcs` directly. The `build` genrule shouldn't really need `include/openssl/opensslv.h` in its `outs` both because that would be a circular dependency as bazel said, and because the genrule doesn't really build that file: it already exists on disk (I assume it's getting captured by the `glob()`)

There may be nicer way to organize the library though, something like this:

```
genrule(
    name = "build_openssl",
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
    outs =  [
        "libssl.a",
        "libcrypto.a",
        "include/openssl/opensslconf.h",
    ],
    .....,
)

cc_library(
    name = "openssl",
    srcs = [":build_openssl"],
    hdrs = [
        "include/openssl/opensslv.h",
        # other headers that openssl should provide
    ],
)
```

then your other rules can depend on the `openssl` `cc_library` and get both the `.a` files and the header files. (I have not tested this though)